# VSTS - External Git

Tags: azure-devops

I've tried to get VSTS to connect to our enterprise Git repository.

To do this I had to get our firewall opened up, and as a result we found that VSTS does not connect to our network using the VSTS domain, ie ########.visualstudio.com

Instead it connects using the IP address of the build agent, which is in the range specified in the Azure Public IP list.

Does anyone know if this is a bug on MS's part?  We could free up our firewall to all the Azure Public IP's, but this is very fragile (they can/will change), and presents a significant security risk as anyone using Azure could attempt to connect to our Git repository.

Interestingly, if you install a private build agent, then VSTS connects to this using the VSTS domain, we have observed this.

Comment: Sounds like a bug...

Comment: Do you mean it use IP when the build agent connect to your Git repo?

Comment: yes it uses one of the public Azure IP addresses.

Comment: it should use the private VSTS domain.  using the Azure public IP is a huge security flaw.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's because the Hosted Build IP updates continuously. You can check the following Q&A:

> **What IP Addresses are used by Hosted Build?**
>
> We have an XML document released every Wednesday that contains all of
>   the IP ranges for Azure Datacenters broken out by region. Please see
>   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=41653:
>   This file contains the Compute IP address ranges (including SQL
>   ranges) used by the Microsoft Azure Datacenters. A new xml file will
>   be uploaded every Wednesday (Pacific Time) with the new planned IP
>   address ranges. New IP address ranges will be effective on the
>   following Monday (Pacific Time). Please download the new xml file and
>   perform the necessary changes on your site before Monday. The Hosted
>   agent should be in the same region as your VSTS account, you need to
>   whitelist the IP address ranges for your region which you can get from
>   the link above.  To verify your region in VSTS navigate to the
>   Settings page at .visualstudio.com/_admin/_home/settings,
>   Under Account you will see a field for Region.

Comment: thanks Cece.  However this does present a significant security hole.  If we open our firewall up to all these IP's then anyone using Azure could try to connect to our Git repo.